# How to set specific security rule on a nested array inside of an object?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I there any way to set a specific security rule on an array inside of a nested object in firebase,
I have the following picture and I want to be able to gain control over the length of the nested array

[image]

```js
request.resource.data.Object.nestedArr.size() == // some criteria
```

the issue however is that what if the array has a different name than nestedArr can there be a certain dynamic rule for this ?

Comment: Can you check this [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67850444/18265570) & [thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62943345/18265570)?

Comment: What do you mean a different name? Where do you get the name from? Or do you mean that there will always be only one field in the `Object` map, and that field will be an array with an arbitrary name?

Comment: the keys are dynamic..

Comment: Have you check above stackoverflow thread?

Comment: @RoopaM i did the issue is i don't know the key name since it is dynamic but I am still investigating to solve this issue..

Comment: @RoopaM however the thread is really good.

Comment: @Richardson900k Dynamic based on what? Where do you get the name from?